# Caching pages in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, caching

I use interceptors in order to cache some pages that rarely updated. Works well, here is the code:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
<property name="cacheSeconds" value="2592000"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
            <property name="cacheMappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="/my/**">0</prop>
                    <prop key="/login">0</prop>
                    <prop key="/logout">0</prop>
                    <prop key="/change-language">0</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Basically, it says the following thing: cache all the pages except of those which are in the `cacheMapping` section. But I have some issue - in case of changing the language the request itself is not cached, but after actual changing I just redirect to the current page and if this page is cached (via previous settings) - user can't see the changes.. I tried to send a `no-cache` in the header (in the redirection request) but seems that interceptor's settings have more priority...

Any suggestions how can I solve it? Thank you in advance.